# Copy SSIS Package Created in SQL Server 2008 onto SQL Server 2005

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2005, ssis, package, deploying

I am having problems moving an SSIS package I created on one server in MS Visual Studio 2008/MS SQL Server 2008 to a server which has MS SQL Server 2005. I am getting the following error and would appreciate your advice:

> Storing or modifying packages in SQL Server requires the SSIS runtime
>   and database to be the same version. Storing packages in earlier
>   versions is not supported.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot nor will you ever be able to create a package in a later version and see it in an earlier version. When they created SSIS for SQL Server 2005, they had no idea what 2008 would contain or how it would be differnt  (or even that the next version would be 2008) so of course you cannot read it.

Do not ever consider developing in a newer version of **anything** than what you need on production. That is a development antipattern.

You must create the package from scratch in SQL Server 2005.

Comment: I wish I could click the "accepted answer" button for you.  This is a perfect answer to the question, but it will probably go "unanswered".